# Typescript index error: looping through keys of typed object

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop

I have an interface that's created as an extension of a couple of other interfaces from an external library:

```
interface LabeledProps extends TextProps, ComponentProps {
    id: string;
    count: number;
    ...
}
```

In another place in the code, I have an object of type `LabeledProps` and I would like to loop through all its properties:

```
function myFunc(props: LabeledProps):void {
    for (let key in props) {
        const val = props[key];  // <-- ERROR IS HERE
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

The line `const val = props[key]` throws a typescript error (though the compiled code actually runs just fine):

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'LabeledProps'.`

What is the right way (or ways) to accomplish this? Thanks!

(*Note*: I know I could add `[key: string]: any` to the interface definition and that will remove the error message, but I would like an actual fix, not just a hiding-the-error fix.)

Comment: can't use `let key:any in props`?

Comment: No, because "the left-hand side of a for...in statement cannot use a type annotation"

Comment: Common pattern to iterate with `for ... in` is: `let key: keyof (typeof obj); for (key in obj) ...`

Comment: @aleksxor Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you want to iterate over object pairwise. There is a useful utility, called `Object.entries`, which removes the error.

```js
type LabeledProps = {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

const obj: LabeledProps = {
    name: 'Maks', age: 18
}

for (let [ key, value ] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunc(props: LabeledProps):void {
    Object.values(props).forEach(val => {
        // do other stuff
    });
}
```

I agree with the other answers here and the comments. The responses of others were all great, and this is only offered as *yet another way to do it*.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `keyof` (object operator) to explicitly tell interpreter. For example:

```
function myFunc(props: LabeledProps):void {
    for (let key in props) {
        const val = props[key as keyof LabeledProps]; 
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```